# Update Collection View after saving a new entity to Core Data

Tags: swift, collectionview, reloaddata, nspersistentcontainer

I am having difficulties updating the collection view, after saving new entity object to persisentContainer. I have to reload the application to see the new data. Ive read similar questions, but they don't appear to be having the same issue that i'm having, since they are able to call reloadData with out any problem.

Code Overflow
popalert requesting user name
save info into core data entity
insert new section in collection view

Basically simplified scheme of what i'm trying to achieve. However, after i save the record, and i attempt to insert a new section with performBatchupdate i get same number of records. I've looked at the values through the cycle and im stuck between two probable causes. The first, my fetch request is not getting new data. Or, the context is not being saved until the application restarts. On restart the new data is loaded, however this is not the case when i push it to background and reopen it.

Below is general code. Looking for any suggestions, or to let me know what i'm missing.

```
class CoreDataUpdateCollectionView {
    
    var name: String!
    var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer!
    
    var users: Users! // Entity fetch request
    // users = fetchRequestController
    have also used fetchRequestController directly
    
    func save(entity: Entity) {
        
        entity.name = name
        
        save(context: persistentContainer)
        
        insertSection()
    }
    
    func save(context: NSPersistentContainer) {
        
        // have also attempted performAndWait
        // assuming that it would run code after block was completed
        context.viewContext.perform {
            try context.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    // I've attempted to wrap this around a DispatchQueue.main.async{}
    // still not reloading since the issue appears to be coming from the persistent store
    func insertSection() {
        
        collectionView.performBatchUpdates {
            // replaced with, collectionView.reloadData() nothing appears to happen in view
            collectionView.insertSection()
        } , { finished in
            // toggled on and off
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    // DataSource Delegate
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numOfItemsIn section: Int) -> {
        // users retur the same number
        return users.count
    }
    
    
    // fetch request controller
    lazy var fetchUserController: NSFetchRequestResult<User> = {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<User> = User.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [
            NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        ]
        fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = [
            "friends"
        ]
        
        let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(
            fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "name",
            cacheName: nil
        )
        
        controller.delegate = self

        do {
            try controller.performFetch()
        } catch {
            fatalError("###\(#function): Failed to performFetch: \(error)")
        }
        
        return controller
    }()
}
```

Comment: Your controller should be at class level not in a function https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/nsfetchedresultscontroller.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH8-SW1

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, is there anything from within the function that should be public to the rest of the files? the function returns the controller, 
 it looks like im following the same logic as shown in the example. Only difference I see is that I return the controller, while the example has a controller at the class level like you mentioned, but this shouldn't  matter, should it?

Comment: It does when functions run the only thing left is what ever it returns by putting it in a computed property you are resetting the controller every time. The controller contains the results it sits at class level and then accessed to get the objects, count, sections, etc. It literally holds your data and the changes.

Comment: Cool man, Thanks a million. I may have not run into this type of case, i assumed that the function would create instances everytime its called. May have been confusing it with something else. The app works now with reloadData(), but not with insertSection. I'll figure this out, but your input was tremendous help.